# How can I reinizialize scrolling for bootstrap modal with jquery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using a bootstrap modal. Inside the modal I have a select box.

```
    $(".selectbox").on("change", function () {
          $(this).select2({
        dropdownParent: $('.parent')
    });
   }
```

But each time I change the selectbox, I am not able to scroll my modal anymore. Is there a jquery code to reinitialize scrolling for modals again?

Comment: whats inside this function ??

Comment: A lot of things, to much to post it here.  I remove some Attributes, add disabled property, initialize select2 element, appending code to element, change data attributes

Comment: doesnot it work by adding overflow-y : auto in inspector after clicking select

Comment: Ok, I could find the line in my code that is causing the problem. I will add it in my question

Comment: @pravinpoudel no overflow-y doesn't work

Comment: I can help you if you could make jsfiddle or something like that for code only , that is related in this question .